# How pass File to testng test method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, testng

I have following directories structure:

**UPDATED STRUCTURE**

```
src
 |
 -test
     |
     -java
     |   |
     |   -SomeXmlTest.java
     |
     -resources
          |
          -someXmlContent.xml
```

I think something like that bad practise:

```
new File(C:\Project ... \src\resources\someXmlContent.xml)

// or magic dance like that
File currentDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir");
File parent = currentDir.getParent();
for (File file:parent.listFiles()){
    //find resources directory and iterate over it files
}
```

I believe that there is simple annotation base solution, for example I just write "src\resources\someXmlContent.xml" in some annotation and testng resolve path automatically, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *resources* instead of *files*. In this way you can pack your application in a jar and retrieve the resource inside of the jar.

Use an InputStream instead of a File/FileInputStream:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/someXml.xml");
```

That is a more generic solution than File.

Comment: But how testng test executes from jar? I want to execute test while compilation by Maven. And the problem is to **access files from testng**, not from application.

Comment: Resources are taken from the class path; they may be in the file system, but also have urls like ".../x.jar!y/z/u.properties".

Answer (score 0):

if you can then refactor your code! it should take input stream instead of file. then use in memory streams (e.g. apache commons IOUtils). this way you don't have access any external resources